# what is a jaxb provider, jaxb handler, and contextResolvers?

Tags: rest, jaxb

1) What is a JaxB provider, and is it the same as a ContextResolver?
2) What is a jaxb handler?

I'm very lost in these terminologies.  Please reply in simple to understand words.

Here it is from the book:

JAXB JAX-RS Handlers

The JAX-RS specification requires implementations to automatically support the marshalling and unmarshalling of classes that are annotated with @XmlRootElement or @XmlType as well as objects wrapped inside javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement instances. Here’s an example that interacts using the Customer class defined earlier:

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id) {

  Customer cust = findCustomer(id);
  return cust;
}

@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
public void createCustomer(Customer cust) {
  ...
```

}
}

As you can see, once you’ve applied JAXB annotations to your Java classes, it is very easy to exchange XML documents between your client and web services. The built-in JAXB handlers will handle any JAXB-annotated class for the application/xml, text/xml, or application/*+xml media types. By default, they will also manage the creation and initialization of JAXBContext instances. Because the creation of JAXBContext instances can be expensive, JAX-RS implementations usually cache them after they are first initialized.
Managing your own JAXBContexts with ContextResolvers

If you are already familiar with JAXB, you’ll know that many times you need to configure your JAXBContext instances a certain way to get the output you desire. The JAX-RS built-in JAXB provider allows you to plug in your own JAXBContext instances. The way it works is that you have to implement a factory-like interface called javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver to override the default JAXBContext creation:

```
public interface ContextResolver<T> {

   T getContext(Class<?> type);
}

ContextResolvers are pluggable factories that create objects of a specific type, for   a certain Java type, and for a specific media type. To plug in your own JAXBContext, you will have to implement this interface. Here’s an example of creating a specific JAXBContext for our Customer class:

@Provider
@Produces("application/xml")
public class CustomerResolver
                  implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
 private JAXBContext ctx;

 public CustomerResolver() {
   this.ctx = ...; // initialize it the way you want
  }


   public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
     if (type.equals(Customer.class)) {
       return ctx;
   } else {
      return null;
   }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Where did you find these terms? These aren't terms from the JDK/JAXB API.

Comment: it's in the restful java with jax-rs 2.0 book.  i have a hard time because words aren't introduced before used.  and as a result, I have to jump between chapters to figure it out.  see my update above.

Answer (score 4):

JAXB is the acronym for "Java Architecture for XML Binding", a specification defining ways to convert between XML documents and Java object trees, originally created by Sun Microsystems. The valid spec, version 2.0, was completed in 2006.

An implementation according to the JAXB specification is a *JAXB provider*.

The specification contains some hints, what a plausible implementation might contain. For instance: "The JAXBContext class is the entry point for a Java application into the
JAXB framework."  It maintains information about the classes to expect during (un)marshalling. It is created either from one or more packages or from a list of classes. (The process of context resolution may follow hints in the annotation.)

The term "JAXB handler" (as it is used in the quoted text) refers to the code associated with a JAXBContext class that investigates a Java class, introspecting fields and methods and annotations, thus creating a database of all information contained within the Java code.

Answer (score 4):

### JAXB Provider

A JAXB provider is an implementation of the [Java Architecture for XML Binding (JSR-222)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) specification.  This specification was created through the Java Community Process.  It was originally lead by Sun Microsystems, but is now lead by Oracle.  The expert group had members from several object-to-XML technologies (XMLBeans, EMF, TopLink OX, etc) as well as several individuals.  A JAXB implementation is required to pass the Test Compatibility Kit (TCK).  Below are links to a couple of JAXB providers:

- https://jaxb.java.net/
- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php

### ContextResolver

JAXB is the default object-to-XML provider in JAX-RS.  By default it will create a `JAXBContext` based on the parameter/return type of the JAX-RS annotated method (i.e. annotated with `@GET`).  Then it will pull in all referenced classes to produce metadata as well. Sometimes this doesn't produce all the required metadata and you need to provide the `JAXBContext` yourself.  This can be done with a `ContextResolver`.

### JAXB Handler

I'm not familiar with this term.